# bad encoding with printing a datatable in R shiny

Tags: r, character-encoding, datatables, shiny, dt

first, sorry for my english because I'm not englophone. And this leads to my problem, in my language, we use accent and other particular characters.
I need to print a data.frame on a shiny datatable (renderDataTable), and some accents are not printed correctly.
[Exemple of lines bas printed, eg 10, 11, 12, 13, 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og0xN.png)

Here is my code, which is inspired from the example of 
Rshiny web site, ref renderDataTable:

```
.libPaths("C:/R_library")
library(shiny)
niveau3 <- read.csv2("Libelle_NC.txt", encoding="UTF-8", header = FALSE, sep = ";", na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(12,
               dataTableOutput("table"),
        )
    )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable(
        {
             niveau3
        },
        options = list(
            pageLength = 15,
            initComplete = I("function(settings, json) {alert('Done.');}")
        )
    )

    output$tableAsiat <- renderDataTable({
        asiat
    })
}

shinyApp(ui= ui , server=server)
```

The file Libelle_NC.txt can be found on the first zip of the [link towards data gouvernement of exportation/importation](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/statistiques-nationales-du-commerce-exterieur/)

The problem is that it seems there is non regularity of the displayed lines:
for exemple line 9 of the rendered table print correctely "...(à..." but not for for line 10.

I look for options to be coded in `options=list()` part of function `renderDataTable` on the option reference link of jQuery DataTable page.
And I didn't find any option about encoding.

I was thinking that it was due to the `read.csv` function which didnt' encode correctly, but a `View(niveau3)` show a well printed data.frame.

Is there any manipulation or option that played on the encoding of a `renderDataTable()`, or should I treat the data.frame before print process?

Thank you.

Comment: If you `cat(niveau3)` in the console does it render correctly?

Comment: @Carl : cat(niveau3) doesn't work. Because niveau3 is a datafatafame, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work, but you could try to reencode `V2` using `niveau3$V2 <- enc2native(niveau3$V2)`

Taken from:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html